# Как использовать продолжение последовательности enumerate?

Tags: python

```
for j in url_pages_2:
    buf = url.replace("?page=1", j)
    response1 = requests.get(buf)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.text, "lxml")
    items1 = soup1.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
    for n, item in enumerate(items1, start=1):
        name1 = item.find("h4", class_="card-title").text.strip()
        price = item.find("h5").text
        print(f'{n} {name1}: {price}')
```

Как продолжить счет нумерации? На странице `?page=1` извлекаемых данных находиться всего 9 позиций  порядок мой нумеруются каждый раз по-новому с 1 до 9 после прохода 1 страницы `?page=1`, как выполнить продолжение последовательности следующего запроса с условной страницы `?page=2`, чтобы счет продолжился с 9 и до 18

Comment: «счет продолжился с 9» — вам нужно чтобы число 9 повторилось дважды?

Comment: А если серьёзно, то просто заведите переменную, хранящую номер текущей страницы, и пихайте её в start с умножением на 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
n = 1 # <---
for j in url_pages_2:
    buf = url.replace("?page=1", j)
    response1 = requests.get(buf)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.text, "lxml")
    items1 = soup1.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
    for n, item in enumerate(items1, start=n): # <---
        name1 = item.find("h4", class_="card-title").text.strip()
        price = item.find("h5").text
        print(f'{n} {name1}: {price}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), чтобы создать объект-счетчик, потом использовать его во внутреннем цикле через `zip`

```
from itertools import count

cnt = count(start=1)
for j in url_pages_2:
    ...
    for item, n in zip(items1, cnt):  
        ...
        print(f'{n} {name1}: {price}')
```

Демонстрация работы:

```
import random
from itertools import count

url_pages_2 = ["page1", "page2", "page3"]
cnt = count(start=1)
for j in url_pages_2:
    items1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    for item, n in zip(items1, cnt):
        name1 = f"{j}_{item}"
        price = random.randint(100, 1000)
        print(f'{n} {name1}: {price}')
```

Вывод:

```
1 page1_item1: 626
2 page1_item2: 380
3 page1_item3: 472
4 page2_item1: 140
5 page2_item2: 480
6 page2_item3: 805
7 page3_item1: 407
8 page3_item2: 655
9 page3_item3: 712
```

`items1` внутри `zip` должно идти первым, потому что если первым будет `cnt`, то в конце итерации по `items1` сначала будет запрошен очередной элемент из `cnt`, потом только `zip` определит, что элементы в `items1` закончились. Получится, что некоторые номера в cnt будут пропущены.

Comment: чет замудренно для меня :)

Comment: @hellog888 ну по-простому, функция count - примерно как range (точнее, как `iter(range())`), только бесконечный. `enumerate` - это как `zip(range(len(items)), items)`, или `zip(count(), items)`, мы этот count выносим наружу и используем в нескольких zip-ах, получается все увеличивающееся и увеличивающееся значение.